# What is the purpose of .git/log

Tags: git, git-stash

I've noticed `.git/log` while searching where git saves stash commits. Found that:

```
$ ls .git/logs/
HEAD  refs 
$ diff .git/refs/ .git/logs/refs/ | head -n3
Common subdirectories: .git/refs/heads and .git/logs/refs/heads 
Common subdirectories: .git/refs/remotes and .git/logs/refs/remotes 
diff .git/refs/stash .git/logs/refs/stash
```

Meaning `stash` - is the only unique file under `logs`. But it doesn't shed light on the rationale for this folder. So what is the purpose of `.git/log` and why git duplicates references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **logs** 
>   Records of changes made to refs are stored in this directory. See git-update-ref[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) for more information. This directory is ignored if $GIT_COMMON_DIR is set and "$GIT_COMMON_DIR/logs" will be used instead.

Reference: [gitrepository-layout](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout)

Answer (score 3):

The `logs` directory is where Git stores the [*reflogs*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Reflogs indicate what your refs pointed to at some earlier point in time. Reflogs store the original commit even after a `git commit --amend`, `git rebase`, etc. Reflogs store a single commit even after a `git pull` pulls in dozens of commits. Reflogs make it easy to undo certain operations.

It's normal for reflogs to exist for all refs you have, and all refs you've had in the recent past. You've had a `stash` ref at some time, through use of the `git stash` command. Even if you no longer have that ref now, the reflog remembers. This lets you undo an accidental branch deletion, for instance, too.

Answer (score 2):

They are the "reflogs" which record the history of where various references in your repository have pointed to in the past.

See [`git help reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and the documentation for `-g, --walk-reflogs` in [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

If you had run `diff -r` you would see many more differences as the `refs/` files all contain a single commit and `logs/refs` contain a history file.

Note that looking that the `refs/` directory is, in general, not a good way to look for refs in your repository. As well as being "loose", refs may also exist only in `packed-refs` and not have a corresponding entry in the `refs/` directory.

Comment: The more important question is what is the use of `logs` while you can obtain all of these information from the other `.git` files?